# .get + dict variable

Tags: python, django

I have a charge object with information in `charge['metadata']['distinct_id']`. There could be the case that it's not set, therefore I tried it that way which doesn't work `charge.get(['metadata']['distinct_id'], None)`

Do you know how to do that the right way?

Comment: `charge.get('metadata', {}).get('distinct_id', None)` or try-except

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what the error is, but, two things possibly wrong

- it should be `charge.get('metadata', None)`
- you can't directly do it on two consecutive levels. If the `metadata` key returns `None`, you can't go on and ask for the `distinct_id` key. You could return an empty dict and apply `get` to that, eg something like `charge.get('metadata', {}).get('distinct_id', None)`

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you query this: the `.get(..)` should be given a *value* for the key, not a list, nor such subscripting syntax. If you write `qux = foo.get('bar')` it is (given `foo` is a dictionary) equivalent to:

```
try:
    qux = foo['bar']
except KeyError:
    qux = None
```

In order to obtain the `charge['metadata']['distinct_id']` in a "safer" way, we can write it like:

```
metadata = charge.get('metadata', None)
if metadata is not None:
    meta_id = metadata.get('distinct_id')
```

In case you want to pass a *chain* of keys, we can make the following helper function:

```
def get_chain(data, *ks, default=None):
    dummy = object()
    for k in ks:
        data = data.get(k, dummy)
        if data is dummy:
            return default
    return data
```

Then we can call this with:

```
meta_id = get_chain(charge, 'metadata', 'distinct_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @blue_note mentioned you could not user two consecutive levels. However your can try something like 
`charge.get('metadata', {}).get('distinct_id')`

here, you tried to get 'metadata' from charge and if it does not found then it will consider blank dictionary and try to get 'distinct_id' from there (technically it does not exists). In this scenario, you need not to worry about if metadata exists or not. If it exists then it will check for distinct_id from metadata or else it throws None.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Cheers..!